# Big Banner for Printing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I have been asked by my college to design a banner for print, this is going to help promote the course we are on etc.

The print size is 500cm x 250cm.

I was going to do this in Photoshop with the following sizes:
50cm x 25cm @ 300DPI

Do you think that these sizes in Photoshop is correct? and would look great printed, not pixelated? I've never designed for something so big before, and when i've entered the full size its over 1gb file size!

Thanks

Comment: This isn't the same. I'm asking about the document dimensions in Photoshop to design a banner this big

Comment: Sickaaron, it **is** indeed a duplicate. Please read **several** of the answers in the duplicate link. Between all the answers in that question, they do contain the information you are seeking. The *chosen* correct answer in the duplicate may not fit your needs directly, but the other answers will.

Comment: well you really shouldn't be using Photoshop to design a banner in the first place ;)  Do you have access to InDesign or Illustrator?

Comment: I designed it in Illustrator! Looks awesome :)